# How to call abstract class method

Tags: java, class, inheritance, abstract

I have an interface called Hospital.java

```
public interface Hospital {
    public void operate();
    public void doScan();
    public void doVaccination();
}
```

I have an abstract class called StreetHospital.java

```
public abstract class StreetHospital implements Hospital{
    public void operate(){
        System.out.println("Street Hospital operate");
  }
}
```

Now I am using another class CommunityHospital.java to extend StreetHospital.java

```
public class CommunityHospital extends StreetHospital{

    public void doScan(){
        System.out.println("CommunityHospital doScan");
    }
    public void doVaccination(){
        System.out.println("CommunityHospital doVaccination");
}
    public void operate(){
        System.out.println("CommunityHospital operate");
    }
}
```

I am creating the CommunityHospital object in my MainHospital class

```
public class MainHospital {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        CommunityHospital ch = new CommunityHospital();
        ch.operate();
        ch.doScan();
        ch.doVaccination();

    }
}
```

I am getting this output:

```
CommunityHospital operate
CommunityHospital doScan
CommunityHospital doVaccination
```

My question is how do I print "Street Hospital operate" sysout statement in output?

Comment: from your main, you can´t, as it´s overriden. In `CommunityHospital` however you could call `super.operate()`.

Comment: Use `super.operate()` in method operate in `CommunityHospital` class. The class `CommunityHospital` is overriding the method and hence no other way as you cannot have two methods with same signature in a class.

Comment: @i_am_zero It doesn't have to be the first line.  (You may be confusing it with the use of `super()` in a constructor, which does have to be first.)

Comment: Really not sure what you're trying to achieve, but you could make another subclass of `StreetHospital`, without its own implementation of the `operate` method; for example `PrivateHospital extends StreetHospital`, then call `operate` on an object of the new class.

Comment: @ajb yea right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another function to `CommunityHospital` with another name say `superOperate` like this:

```
public void superOperate(){
    super.operate();
}
```

and call it from anywhere

Comment: Thanks for this.. It works. Is there any other way also instead of using super keyword?

Comment: @nsd the only way to access parent's methods is super.I think there is no other way.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that.

There can't be two methods in one class with same name and param. Once you override operate() in CommunityHospital , the same mthod in StreetHospital no longer exist.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `super` keyword to invoke the superclass members in the subclass as shown below:

```
public class CommunityHospital extends StreetHospital{

    public void doScan(){
        System.out.println("CommunityHospital doScan");
    }
    public void doVaccination(){
        System.out.println("CommunityHospital doVaccination");
    }
    public void operate(){
        super.operate();//call super class operate to get StreetHospital features
        //If you want, you can add CommunityHospital features here
    }
}
```

I suggest you look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) for more details and understand the concept.

> If your method overrides one of its superclass's methods, you can
>   invoke the overridden method through the use of the keyword **super**.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to remove the `operate` method from `CommunityHospital` class.

In terms of design that would mean that community hospital's operate does not differ from a street hospital's operate.

Another consideration would be that you actually want street hospital's operate and then there are some specifics that need to be accomplished in community hospital's operate. For that `CommunityHospital` `operate` function should look like:

```
public void operate() {
        super.operate(); //Street hospital operate
        // Add community hospital operate details here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are extending a class, but then overwriting its methods. So whenever you call `operate` it will use the one in `CommunityHospital` which is the overwritten one. If you remove that, it will find the `operate` method from the `StreetHospital` class.

If for some reason you do need an `operate` method in `CommunityHospital`, don't implement a new one and just call `super.operate()`. This will call the `StreetHospital` class' `operate` method.

Answer (score 1):

**CommunityHospital** overrides the operate method, so if that class doesn't call super then is not possible...

do modify the class like:

```
 public void operate(){
        super.operate(); // call the method from super class

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void operate(){
        super.operate(); // call the method from super class

    }
```

or just remove

```
@Override
    public void operate() {
        System.out.println("CommunityHospital operate");
    }
```

form CommunityHospital

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write `StreetHospital` in a way so that subclasses can override `operate()`, but the `StreetHospital`'s `operate()` (the non-overridden one) can still be called, you could do this:

```
public abstract class StreetHospital implements Hospital {
    public final void streetOperate() {
        System.out.println("Street Hospital operate");
    }
    public void operate() {
        streetOperate();
    }
}
```

Now `operate()` can be overridden, but `streetOperate()` can still be called on any `CommunityHospital` object, or any other subclass of `StreetHospital`.

However, it's really difficult for me to think of an actual case where this would be a good design.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by using `super`

```
class CommunityHospital extends StreetHospital{
    // same code
    public void operate(){
        super.operate(); //-> this line
        //System.out.println("CommunityHospital operate");
    }
}
```

You could also make the `operate` method `final`, if you don't want to allow overriding of it.

```
abstract class StreetHospital implements Hospital{
    final public void operate(){
        System.out.println("Street Hospital operate");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't  override the operate method, it will be available in your class when you extend it.

So don't override the operate method in your class when you are extending it.

```
public class CommunityHospital extends StreetHospital {
   public class CommunityHospital extends StreetHospital {

    public void doScan() {
        System.out.println("CommunityHospital doScan");
    }

    public void doVaccination() {
        System.out.println("CommunityHospital doVaccination");
    }
}
```

This shall work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no other way than calling `super.operate` in subclass.

Upcasting in java doesn't work. Demo that shows it:

```
package com.stackoverflow.main;

class A {
    void operate() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    void operate() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A b = new B();
        ((A) b).operate();
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
B
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the concept of  down casting .
I have written the code in C#

```
abstract class MyClass1 {
    public void operate() {
        System.Console.WriteLine("base class");
    }
    public abstract void operate1();
    public virtual void operate2() {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Virtual");
    }
}

class myclass2 : MyClass1 {
    public override void operate1() {
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
    }
    public override void operate2() {
        Console.WriteLine("overidden");
    }
    public new void operate() {
        Console.WriteLine("!base class");
    }
}

class program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        MyClass1 m = new myclass2();
        m.operate();
    }
}
```

Comment: As you cannot create a instance of a abstract class but you can create it's reference variable .